# How to use a newly purchased house as a proof of accommodation in the UK if my name is not on the deed yet?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-of-accommodation

My parents are planning to visit us in the UK and we are in the process of getting all the documentation for the visa application. However I need a bit of advice regarding the accommodation proof that has to be included with the application.

We have just bought a 4-bed house this month, unfortunately I was advised by mu solicitor that the land registry document which shows our ownership in the property could take up to 3 months. We are planning to submit the application next month. At this point I am not sure what can we submit as an accommodation proof.

Comment: Probably just state that to them and I'm sure there was some legal agreement for the purchase; Use that even if the registry is not in your name yet?

Comment: @HankyPanky Many thanks for your reply. We do have a docuemt from our solicitor mentioning the completion of the purchase of the property. Would that be enough along with the new council tax  and utility bills of 1 month for the new house

Comment: We can’t really tell if that will be enough but then that’s the reality and the house actually does belong to you so presenting any relevant evidence to support that should be fine imho. There is no strict requirement for it to be a title deed

Comment: Great! Thanks@HankyPanky. Really appreciate it!

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf

Comment: @HankyPanky coulnd you convert your comments into an answer? Ping me and I'll upvote.

Answer (score 3):

A simple statement should be enough, essentially an invitation letter, saying your parents will visit you in your home (note the address), a private property, during a specified time period (note the dates), and that there is enough room.

While it is unlikely that proof of ownership is requested, Council tax addressed to you at the new address should work. If more is needed, an executed sales contract should suffice, as the property conveyance document would show the transfer to you and the date.